# How to convert character encoding from Windows exec output in TCL

Tags: windows, tcl

I'm just going mad with this one. I've already read everything: answers, wiki & manual pages with no luck.

I need to convert the output returned from a Windows command in a TCL script preserving full characters localization, the output of an 'exec' command I mean.

So, let's say:

```
catch { exec cmd.exe /C dir } _output

puts $_output
```

This will print any localized character as not correctly shown.

Any advice to solve this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried using [`encoding convertfrom`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/encoding.htm#M6)?

Comment: @Shawn Yes, tried that too, nothing changes except wrong chars being replaced by some other wrong ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the encoding isn't correct by default — it isn't the same as the result of `encoding system`, which is also the encoding of filenames and miscellaneous other strings fed into the OS — then you can't use `exec`. But all is not lost. Instead of `exec`, use this:

```
# Open as a binary pipeline
set f [open |[list cmd.exe /C dir] "rb"]
set data [read $f]
close $f
```

Now you have the literal bytes from the command, *whatever they are,* and can use `encoding convertfrom` to handle the mess, possibly with the help of `regexp` and `string range` and so on to slice-and-dice that string as required. After all, binary data in Tcl is just another kind of string.

---

If you're just using this to list the filenames, use the built-in `glob` command instead. It's much faster and avoids all these problems except in the most intensely weird cases (such as with strange external devices with wrong filesystem-level metadata).

Comment: In theory you can change `encoding system`'s result. In practice, that's virtually always a horrible mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and detailed answer Donal, I'll try soon this approach on my code (still not clear to me how it works actually...). Meanwhile I've found another possible solution, I need some time to test both. Bye.

Comment: Internally, `exec` works by opening a pipeline, reading the results from the pipeline's stdout, and closing the pipeline. The approach above just decomposes that. I probably ought to add it to the manual page examples; working with binary output isn't _that_ uncommon.

Comment: Ok, your solution (of course) works, `convertfrom cp850 $data` now converts everything.
My solution works too, basically I generate a .cmd temporary file (tcl side) to exec later.
The batch file contains a `CHCP 65001` command -before- the DIR statement (DIR is just an example to generate an output) to set the charset of the original environment to utf-8.
I've just found 65001 is the utf8 charset on Windows.
Finally `encoding convertfrom utf-8 ...` can handle the correct conversion.
Now I understand the whole stuff much better.
Thanks again Donal!